# Informix SQL - Is there a way to dynamically retrieve only dates which fall on a certain day?

Tags: sql, informix

I'm looking for a way to get only timestamps which only occur on Mondays.  So, for example, if I have a timestamp like `2013-07-22 00:30:28:584`, it should match the query, while the same timestamp on the next day should not (i.e., `2013-07-23 00:30:28:584`).

I know I can hardcode the dates in the SQL query with something like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE DATE(my_timestamp) IN ('2013-08-12', '2013-08-05', ... , '2013-03-04');
```

But I'm hoping there's a way to figure it out dynamically in the query without having to specifically list the desired dates.

I thought of doing something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE DATE(my_timestamp) = TODAY - INTERVAL(6) DAY TO DAY;
```

... but this would only get the *last* Monday rather than *all* Mondays, and the `INTERVAL(?)` would have to be updated depending on the day the SQL was executed regardless.

Does anyone know of a way to do that?  Or if it's simply impossible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `weekday` function:

```
where weekday(my_timestamp) = 1;
```

It is documented [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1535.htm).

Comment: Thank you so much, sir.  Would have never found that from the endless Googling with all the wrong keywords.